# Blog missing after Orchard 1.4 upgrade

Tags: orchardcms

I've recently upgraded my Orchard site to version 1.4. Since I had an source code enlistment I just updated to the latest Default branch, and built and deployed the new version. Since the deployment, my blog is totally missing. Thinking it had something to do with the new Autoroute feature, I enabled the Migrate14 module and migrated to 1.4, but still the blog is totally missing in both the Admin UI and at the site.

Do anyone have any ideas on what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have "Blog" feature enabled, this is the first thing.

Second - please check the logs in /App_Data/Logs for any exceptions being thrown and paste your findings here. This could give us a bit more detail.

Third - try upgrading your source to recent 1.x branch. I've been setting up a site using that one yesterday (also upgraded to 1.4) and everything went smoothly.

See this answer's comments for more information related to solution.

Comment: Thanx for you input, which lead me to the solution. The Blog was Enabled. I looked into the logs and saw the following: NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: TitlePartRecord of: Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemVersionRecord. That looked kinda suspicious, so I googled it and found this post at the Orchard discussion forum: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/285966. I followed bertrandleroy's advice and deleted mappings.bin. Voila, the blog was back, but with missing Titles. I re-published the posts ant the Titles and Routes were back.

Comment: So, it seems that it is very important that the Title feature is enabled before you do run the Migrate14 module. I guess this could have been stressed a bit more in the upgrade instructions. However, I'm now happy to be back up running with some help from the fantastic Orchard CMS development community. Thanks!